# how to display image in UIImageView in a specifc block of window in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a window in which I want to display an image in a specific block of that window. The image is retrieved from the local XML file. I parsed the XML file and got the image value in the log, but I don't know how to put it in that specific block. The below image pasted for the reference.

[image: UIImageVIew]

The arrow mark represents that within this UIImageView I need to get the image. Also, I doubt that I need to mention any name for reference to UIIMageView in storyboard. Suggest me an idea.

**Edited**

My parser code:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample.xml"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
[xmlParser setDelegate:theParser]
```

After this I am using this code for getting image:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/administrator/Desktop/imageApp/resources/Main_pic1.png"];
```

After this I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to create `IBOutlet` in .h file

like `IBOutlet UIImageView *imgview;` and connect imgview with your `UIImageview` from xib.

After that you can set image to image view.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[your url which u get form local xml]];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

imgview.image=image;
```

Ttry this, It may help you.

Comment: fine. If its more image in xml how that is possible to do. Kindly suggest for this too.

Comment: so you want to show all your images in single uiimageview or you want to create different imageview for every image url you have in xml ???\

Comment: different imageview from xml

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the url image to Uiimageview by :

```
YourImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:YourUrl];
```

It's possible to do the equivalent by going through NSData, but it's a bad idea. Instead, the image should be downloaded asynchronously using NSURLConnection, and only once it's fully downloaded should it be converted into a UIImage and assigned to the image view.

Save all your urls in an say **NSMutableArry *UrlArray** then

```
int x = 0;
int y = 10;

for (int i = 0; i< [UrlArray]; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3+x,y, 80,
    80)]autorelease];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    if (x >= 300)
    {
        x = 0;

        y = y+imageView.frame.size.height+3;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x+3 , y, 80, 80);

    }


     CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[UrlArray ObjectAtIndex:i]];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:beginImage];
    x = x+imageView.frame.size.width+5;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

will do the work i guess;

Comment: but am having the data elements and the image elements in the xml if so how can i avoid that NSData

Comment: what i understand is that you are getting the image binary data in xml only with some tag am i right?? if that is so then you can pass that binary data directly to imageview by *imgview.image =[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]  *

Comment: After: 
*UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/administrator/Desktop/imageApp/resources/Main_pic1.png"];*
yourImageView.image = image;

this is for one image.

Comment: ok can you say what is that " .image " ; Also if i have multiple images that should be viewd in different UIImageView how to take this code

Comment: edited my answer .image is the property of uiimageview by which we can set an image in uiimageview.

Comment: ya am trying your edited answer. also i tried that .image it shows me an error " property of 'image' not found on object type UIImage, did you mean images " if i change so it says again error " Assignment to readonly property "

Comment: try my new edit i am not at my machine so facing some problem i guess it should work

Comment: you can also try using this framework https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading

Comment: ya sure modifying my code according to your new edit. let me tel you if i get success in it

Comment: This line CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[urlArray ObjectAtIndex:i]]; shows me ARC semantic issue error No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'ObjectAtIndex:'

Comment: well if you are using ARC you have to handle things likewise .